# Is it true that $\overline{A \cap \overline{B}} = \overline{A \cap {B}}$?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I was trying to understand Willard's proof (the book is called Topology) about local compacteness that any subset of a Hausdorff space is the intersection of an open set and a closed set.
Then I came across this post: [Locally compact subspace is an intersection of an open and closed set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/643946/locally-compact-subspace-is-an-intersection-of-an-open-and-closed-set).
But I can't prove
$$(1) \quad \overline{W_x \cap \overline{M}} = \overline{W_x \cap {M}}$$
(wich is very similar to what Willard does $\overline{W_x \cap {M}} \subseteq X \implies  \overline{W_x} \cap M \subseteq X$).

How does one prove $(1)$?  Thank you for the help.

Comment: you can't prove this, because it's false - it could be that $A \cap B$ is empty and $A \cap \bar B$ is not

Comment: I found out exactly what I was looking for in @QuantumSpace 's answer in here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3584098/a-locally-compact-and-dense-subset-of-a-hausdorff-space-is-open

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Let $A=(0,1)\cup \{2\}$,  and $B=(2,3)$ then $\overline{A\cap \overline{B}}=\{2\}\ne\emptyset =\overline{A\cap B}$,

Comment: @Angelo yes. Thanks!

Comment: You could also have let $A=[0,2]$ and $B=(2,3)$.